# Find value in different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to write some code that will, for example, select the value in cell A2 in Sheet 2, compare it with the range A:A in Sheet 1, and if it finds the same value, it copies some values from that row in Sheet 1 and pastes them in Sheet 2. Then it looks at cell A3 in Sheet 2 and repeats the process. Then cell A4 in Sheet 2 etc.

I'm lost from here on out. Any ideas?

```
Sub Last_Week()

Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet

Set Sheet2 = ActiveSheet
Set Sheet1 = ActiveSheet.Previous

Sheet1.Activate

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 1500
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=(ACTIVATE WS AND SELECT THE VALUE IN COLUMN A AND ROW I)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
'do it something

    Else
'do it another thing
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Last_Week()


Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 1500
    'search cell A & i from Sheet2 in column A in Sheet1
    Set cell = Sheet1.Columns("A:A").Find(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
    'do it something
    Else
    'do it another thing
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```